# Is there a way to dynamically stack barcharts?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to stack bar charts but they always blend in with each other while I want the biggest one to be furthest to the back and the smallest one to be to the front.

[image]

I've tried and failed to find a solution to this problem.

```
style.use("ggplot")
pyplot.bar(Type, HP, color = "Green", clip_on = "True")
pyplot.bar(Type, ATK, color = "Red")
pyplot.bar(Type, DEF, color = "Grey")
pyplot.bar(Type, SpATK, color = "Crimson")
pyplot.bar(Type, SpDEF, color = "Black")
pyplot.bar(Type, Speed, color = "Orange", clip_on = "true")
pyplot.autoscale()
pyplot.ylabel("Average Stats")
pyplot.xlabel("Type of Pokemon")
pyplot.legend(("Health Points", "Attack", "Defense", "Special Attack", "Special Defense", "Speed"), loc = 'best')
pyplot.show()
```

I would like the graph which I linked above but simply ordered in the correct way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are not producing a *stacked*  chart here. Instead you have one where bars just overlap. So do you want bars to overlap/order in the correct way, or do you want a stacked chart?

Comment: IIUC, you could make a pandas DataFrame and plot bar, so that the columns are place text to each other but not overlapped. Your proposed way of sorting bars from back to front could really be confusing,